# "Memory IS RAM!" - How true is this?

Tags: memory

A famous IT technician once said that memory is RAM.

This would mean memory is equal to ram, however this cannot be true as Hark Disk Drive space is also memory that cannot be converted to RAM.

Is RAM just memory, or is it a part of memory?

Comment: Is the title referring to the quote [Jen, memory *is* ram](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdREEcfaihg) or is it a coincidence?

Comment: this question might of been useful 10 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_memory):

> In computing, memory refers to the physical devices used to store
>   programs (sequences of instructions) or data (e.g. program state
>   information) on a temporary or permanent basis for use in a computer
>   or other digital electronic device.

So RAM and hard disks are both types of memory.  The former being temporary and the latter is permanent.

Comment: From a programer's and CPU standpoint, this makes sense.  You don't directly interact with anything else except memory.  Files on disk are copied into memory. Network traffic is accessed thought memory.

Answer (score 4):

Officially

```
 **R**andom
 **A**ccess
 **M**emory
```

Technically, the type of RAM we are talking about loses all data when the power is off(volatile) , and your hard drive does not.(non-volatile)

Hard drive is storage can be used to extend RAM, but it is much slower.

Windows does this all the time it is called your swap file unless you reconfigured your windows.  By default there is a hidden file called pagefile.sys on one of your hard drives and when windows runs out of real memory it uses swapfile.

Answer (score 0):

RAM is memory, but memory isn't RAM.

RAM is just a really fast version of memory. Hard drive space is also memory.

Answer (score 0):

RAM is in fact a type of memory storage. Programs can save different types of variables (strings, integers, etc.) on named location of the RAM. It can't be used like a Flash Drive, unfortunately, (believe me, I wish it could)

And referencing Keltari's answer, Wikipedia is an untrustworthy source. Remember, anybody can post anything on there and it be inaccurate and/or false

Answer (score -1):

RAM is memory, but memory isn't RAM.

RAM is just a really fast version of memory. Hard drive space is also memory.

On the other hand,

RAM is in fact a type of memory storage. Programs can save different types of variables (strings, integers, etc.) on named location of the RAM. It can't be used like a Flash Drive, unfortunately, (believe me, I wish it could)

And referencing Keltari's answer, Wikipedia is an untrustworthy source. Remember, anybody can post anything on there and it be inaccurate and/or false